# Update pip3 for Python 3.6?

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, python-3.6

I just upgraded from Python 3.4 to Python 3.6 using Homebrew.

The output states:

```
Pip, setuptools, and wheel have been installed. To update them
  pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I tried to run

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

But it does not upgrade pip for Python 3.6. Instead it finds pip3 in in Python 3.4 and says 'requirement satisfied':

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-33.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (472kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 481kB 1.0MB/s 
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 5.7MB/s 
Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel
  Found existing installation: setuptools 12.0.5
    Uninstalling setuptools-12.0.5:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-12.0.5
Successfully installed setuptools-33.1.1 wheel-0.29.0
```

When I check the pip version, it is in Python 3.4, not 3.6. How do I resolve this?

```
$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Answer (score 14):

Not a good idea to install and try to use Python3.4 and 3.6 without [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

You can however tell the terminal on your mac which Python pip to use with:

```
python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

You can change python3.6 to python3.4 if you need to use pip on the older Python3 version.

Comment: Indeed, I have these two versions of python in CentOS. They really confuses me. :-(

Comment: @MartinZhai, can you find a solution?

Comment: @Barny I used absolute path to tell system which Python I want to use. And you can set alias for them in your bash profile for convenience.

Comment: advice on how to install pip3.6 with python3.6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622410/1731460

Answer (score 5):

A temporary fix could be:

```
alias "pip3.6"="python3.6 -m pip $1"
```

This will allow you to go `pip3.6 install somemodule` or `pip3.6 install --upgrade somemodule`

Answer (score 0):

When I execute `python36 -m pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, I got the error:

```
/usr/bin/python36: No module named pip3
```

My solution is the following:

```
python3.6 -m ensurepip    
python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```