# Python 3.6 No module named pip

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6, fedora

I have just installed Python 3.6 on Fedora 25 (64 bits) by running `dnf install python36` and I can't use any modules Python 3.5 can otherwise use just fine, for example, PyCharm complains about setup tools not being installed, also I can run python3 and issue:

```
import aiohttp
```

However, if run python36 and then:

```
import aiohttp
```

I instead get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'

Pip is also not present on python36, as python36 -m pip throws:

> /usr/bin/python36: No module named pip

I have to note that I've got python 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6 installed at the same time, both 3.4 and 3.5 working just fine

Answer (score 104, accepted):

On **Fedora 25** Python 3.6 comes as a minimalistic version without `pip` and without additional `dnf` installable modules.

But you can manually install `pip`:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
```

After that you can use it as `python3.6 -m pip` or just `pip3.6`.

Comment: Ty for the suggestion, by the way is there a link to a source with more info? I'd like to know any other problems I may run into with 3.6.

Comment: It''s for developers. See `dnf info python36` for details.

Comment: You are right, I actually managed to install the full stack by compiling 3.6 form source code, not the best solution IMO but it just works, though my python3 command has been replaced for python3.6 instead of 3.5, I'll have to work around that issue.

Comment: After much search, this is what worked on my mac, where I had the same problem, when trying to install pybind11. The python binary used in my case was in /opt/local/bin/python3.6,

Comment: @acme64 try `python3.6 -m pip`

Comment: on a fresh machine, you may get `No module named 'distutils.util'`. Be sure to first run `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` before installing pip.

Comment: @hughes The question was for Fedora 25. `apt-get` exists on Debian based distributions only.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks, I missed that. This question is currently the first google result for "python3 no module named pip"

Comment: Use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py for 3.6 version, the mentioned link works for Python >=3.7

Answer (score 55):

In Debian distributions, you can run

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip ##for python2

sudo apt-get install python3-pip ##for python3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo dnf install python3
```

Try this.