# "No module named pip", "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using"

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, pip, windows-10, virtualenv

First of all, I've already looked for some solution that will work, but without success.
So... I've got a problem:
I need to install python 3.5.4, virtualenv, and django into virtualenv.
Python installed, virtualenv installed via

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Virtualenv created using

```
virtualenv.exe burt
```

but after that there is some problem...

```
PS C:\projects\bikeu_reporting> .\burt\Scripts\activate
(burt) PS C:\projects\bikeu_reporting> pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\projects\bikeu_reporting\burt\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\projects\bikeu_reporting\burt\Scripts\pip.exe" '
(burt) PS C:\projects\bikeu_reporting> python -m pip
C:\projects\bikeu_reporting\burt\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
(burt) PS C:\projects\bikeu_reporting> python -m pip install
C:\projects\bikeu_reporting\burt\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
```

Do you have any clues what to do? It's not my first time installing these kind of environment, but the first time with these problems.

---

EDIT

What I've already tried:

1. Python reinstallation to path without spaces
2. Different python version: 3.6.8
3. python -m pip install pip --upgrade
4. Uninstall python, remove all related folders, reinstallation
5. pip3 instead of pip
6. get-pip.py

---

I've found something that bothers me:

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
 '"c:\projects\bikeu_reporting\burt\ **scripts** \python.exe"
"C:\projects\bikeu_reporting\burt\ **Scripts** \pip.exe"

path for python is all small letters, but path for pip is with capitals

---

What a mess...
Small and capital letters are good direction for "Unable to create process using". I've edited pip.exe from virtualenv and substituted **/scripts/** with **/Scripts/** . So now I've got only No module error:

```
(burt) PS C:\projects\bikeu_reporting> pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python37\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\projects\bikeu_reporting\burt\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

---

The same virtualenv but PowerShell:

```
PS C:\projects\test> .\testenv\Scripts\activate
(testenv) PS C:\projects\test> python
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\projects\\test\\testenv\\Scripts\\python.exe'
>>>
```

cmd.exe:

```
(testenv) c:\projects\test>python
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\marci\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\python.exe'
>>>
```

Comment: I am assuming you have already tried this but it wasn't in the list. I always have to type pip3 instead of pip... hopefully this helps but I'm not sure, just throwing it out there.

Comment: I've tried that, the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.6 No module named pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622182/python-3-6-no-module-named-pip) install pip manually

Comment: get-pip.py added to the list of already tried solutions.

Comment: I have the same problem with 3.7.3, `powershell` and `venv`.  It works ok from the global installation but not the virtual environment.  This has worked for me for  a long time, and I haven't knowingly updated anything, so I don't know what's changed.  I'm suspicious of that space in the `Fatal error in launcher` line but can't seem to solve it.

Comment: It doesn't look like mine is exactly the same problem, but FWIW installing the virtual environment into a directory without spaces works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally used https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-win/ and environment created by it somehow work with vscode, so decided to give up on previous problems.