# aws sam deployment failed due to pip executable not found - python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am attempting to perform a sam deployment and upon running the command:

`sam build --template template.yaml --build-dir ./build --use-container`

I see that the image "amazon/aws-sam-cli-build-image-python3.6" is successfully pulled but then I obtain the following error:

`Build Failed Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - pip executable not found in your python environment at /var/lang/bin/python3.6`

I really have no clue why this is happening since I would expect that once the python image was pulled, pip and its dependencies would be installed.

Appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: are you create your lambda with python 3.6 ?

Comment: yes, is that a problem? in my template.yaml I have


``` Handler: app.lambda_handler_entry
      Runtime: python3.6
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 20 ```

Comment: please post your yaml too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into this same problem as well. The issue was that I needed to upgrade the version of Pip installed by Homebrew to 20.3, which uses Python's new script wrapper format.

I ran this command, which ultimately resolved the issue:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Note that I'm using the command python3 and not python. Python3 is the PATH variable for Homebrew's specific installation of Python.

Anyway, after I ran this, my sam build command worked without issues.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the pip for your python distribution
like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

More in this link: [Python 3.6 No module named pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622182/python-3-6-no-module-named-pip/62002638#62002638)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue after installing the sam-cli with pipx (I also use pyenv). My global python version from pyenv was 3.6 and the sam-cli was somehow finding python at /usr/bin/python3.8 instead of the pyenv shim. After setting the local python version to 3.8.6 with pyenv's .python-version file in the root of the project, the error message went away.

Answer (score 1):

When i use  sam build, got the error :

```
Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - pip executable not found in your python environment at ..\Python310\python.EXE
```

*Note: I also have Python-a 3.11  version

Troubleshooting flow:

1. I entered the command python3.10 --version and got the error

   python3.10 : The term 'python3.10' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2. I went to "Control Panel" > "System and Security" > "System" > "Advanced system settings". Click the "Environment Variables..." button. and there I saw that there is a path to my folder \Python310\ , I i renamed python.exe to python3.10 , and now on the command python3.10 --version I was getting Python 3.10.6
3. I entered the command python3.10 -m ensurepip  and I got

   installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
   Successfully installed pip-22.2.1 setuptools-63.2.0

**Problem solved.**

Answer (score 0):

You're missing pip to resolve dependencies.

Try to install:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```