# Problem with install pyinstaller with pip

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller, linux-mint

I had a problem, when installing pyinstaller with `pip install pyinstaller`, I got the message `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable.` I tried to install using the command `python3 -m pip install pyinstaller`, it gave the error `/ usr / bin / python3: No module named pip.` How I can solve this problem and still install pyinstaller? I have linux mint 20.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable" python message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65808972/defaulting-to-user-installation-because-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable)

Comment: When using _pyhon3_ you have to install pip for version 3: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622182/python-3-6-no-module-named-pip#44622410)