# How to install Python3.6's pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Well, on My Ubuntu I have three versions of Python: Python2.7, Pyhton3.5 and Python3.6.

I have to install a package that only support python3.6. 
But when I input `pip3 install packagename`, I was always told `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement packagename`.

When I input pip3 -V, It tells me

`pip 9.0.1 from /home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)`.

And I can't install pip3.6 with `sudo apt install python3.6-pip` command.
So What should I do to install that package in my python3.6 Or What should I do to install pip3.6 in my conputer?

Comment: This answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41688045/4900574

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python3.6 should come with pip installed. Run it like this:

```
python3.6 -m pip install <packagenmae>
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662104/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-6-on-ubuntu-16-10/44254088#44254088) post.