# Python3 virtualenv installs python2

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

I am not sure what is wrong but I can't seem to get python3 in a virtualenv environment. I tried upgrading my ubuntu and updating all the packages - but no luck:

```
python3 -m virtualenv ENV
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/ramin/projects/buybulkamerica/ENV/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/ramin/projects/buybulkamerica/ENV/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
```

What can I do to ensure that virtualenv installs python3 instead of python2?

Comment: Is this helping? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv
I could reproduce your problem and running it as in the accepted answer worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python 3 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have installed virtualenv using pip, it doesn't matter if you used pip or pip3 if you give the location of your python3 installation to the virtualenv command, like this.

Create new virtualenv
`virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 environmentname`

Access virtualenv
`source /environmentname/bin/activate`

If this doesn't work, use complete path from `pwd`

`source /complete/path/to/environmentname/bin/activate`

Stop virtualenv
`deactivate`

Comment: Thanks this did the job, but what about pip?

Comment: What about pip? Do you mean pip inside the virtualenv? It should be installed when you create the virtualenv, and then you can install any modules into the virtualenv when you have it activated

Comment: I meant to ask how to I specify the pip location/version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688016/update-pip3-for-python-3-6 something like this?

Answer (score 2):

First, uninstall existing virtualenv.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge python-virtualenv` if you installed it using a package manager.

`pip uninstall virtualenv` if you have installed it using pip.

`pip3 uninstall virtualenv` if you have installed it using pip3.

Any one of the above commands will work.

Now install virtualenv again. Since you want python3, you need to run the following command.

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

That should do the trick. Now when you create a new virtualenv, it will use python3.

There may be a better way but I had the same problem and after not finding any solution I tried this and it worked.